# extjs keyMap dynamic keys

Tags: extjs, keymapping

Hi I have this implemented and I want the keys to be dynamic based on function return. Lets say I have function in controller called "returnKeyFront" which returns "F" key. I then want to take it and apply it for first element F. So instead of writing F there would be that function which returns that key. No idea how to implement that. I am using keyMap from extJS with coffescript. THX

```
  keyMap: 
   F: 
    handler: "onCamerasHotkeyFront"      
   B: 
    handler: "onCamerasHotkeyBack"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a helper function.

Something like this (I did not test it, but should be a pretty good hint.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.KeyChain', {
    singleton: true,

    /**
     * holds the current keymap appwide
     * @private
     */
    _keymap: null,

    /**
     * initialize with a base defintion 
     */
    initKeyChain() {
        const keyChain = this.definition;

        this.updateKeyMap();
    },

    /**
     * base definition. You can also set it to null
     * if you want to start blank
     *
     * @private
     */
    definition: {
        CameraFront: {
            key: 'f',
            alt: true,
            fn: 'onCamerasHotkeyFront',
            scope: this // typically you want to either set the fn and/or scope
        },
        CameraBack: {
            key: 'f',
            alt: true,
            fn: 'onCamerasHotkeyBack',
            scope: this // typically you want to either set the fn and/or scope
        },
    },

    /**
     * changeKey
     * to add or change a definition. You can also init via changeKey
     * see this.defintion for examples on how keyDefinition should look like
     *
     * @arg {string}          type  e.g. 'CameraFront'
     * @arg {object}          keyDefinition
     * @arg {string}          keyDefinition.key
     * @arg {boolean}         [keyDefinition.alt]
     * @arg {function|string} keyDefinition.fn
     * @arg {scope}           [keyDefinition.scope]
     */
    changeKey(type, keyDefinition) {
        if(!keyDefinition.scope) keyDefinition.scope = this;
        if(typeof keyDefinition.fn === 'string') keyDefinition.fn = scope[definition.fn];

        MyApp._definition[type] = keyDefinition;
        this.updateKeyMap();
    },

    /**
     * updateKeyMap
     * 
     * @private
     */
    updateKeyMap() {
        if(this._keymap) this._keymap.destroy();

        const newBinding = this.createBindings();

        this._keymap = new Ext.util.KeyMap({
            target: Ext.getBody(),
            binding: newBindings
        });
    },

    /**
     * createBinding
     * 
     * @private
     */
    createBinding() {
        const def = this.definition;
        let bindings = [];

        Ext.Object.each(def, function(key, value) {
            bindings.push({value});
        });

        return bindings;
    }
});
```